# ffmpeg loop not found error

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I am trying to use image.gif as a still for the entire duration of audio.mp3, and make a video from it. here is the current command I am using

`ffmpeg -i audio.mp3 -loop 1 -i image.gif -acodec copy video.avi`

this works, but goes on for ages constantly increasing audio file, which makes me believe it's looping the mp3 file or something.

I tried changing the audio/image around, but it doesn't work and says:

`Option loop not found.`

I tried `-shortest` too, which I thought matched the length to the audio, but it makes the file twice the size of the MP3 + the size of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

nvm, it was just the video making the file that large. sorted using 1 FPS

`ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.gif -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy -shortest -r 1 video.avi`

I believe the loop was just in the wrong order, and this is an explanation of the output

-loop (loop image)

-i (input for image and then the audio file)

-acodec copy (copy mp3 file, don't re-encode)

-shortest (make video as short as possible)

-r 1 (force 1 FPS)

video.avi (output file)